# Show that partial derivative is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, partial-derivative

Given a function $f \,:\, \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ I have shown the partial derivative $f_x$ exists and that $|f_x(x_1, y) - f_x(x_2, y)| \leq 16 |y|$.

Is it possible to show that $f_x$ is a continuous function using the [epsilon-delta criterium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit)?

Comment: No. The inequality you have proved does not say anything about continuity if $f_x$ at a point $(a,b)$ with $b \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider

$$
f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
x,& \text{ if } y=0 \\
0,& \text{ otherwise }\\
\end{cases}
$$
That means
$$
f_x(x,y)=\begin{cases}
1,& \text{ if } y=0 \\
0,& \text{ otherwise }\\
\end{cases}
$$

which is not continuous at any point $(x,0)$.